# Frequency/Contingency table along 1 dimension in R

Tags: r, frequency, find-occurrences

I'm trying to count co-occurrences along a single dimension. It's somewhat similar to win/loss, dominance matrices, or frequency tables, (and spectrograms/raster plots) but without directionality and along 1 variable.

Here's an example of the data:

```
  person response
1      a        1
2      a        2
3      a        4
4      b        1
5      b        2
6      c        2
7      c        4
8      d        4
9      d        3
```

The goal would be to get an `n x n` matrix as the one shown below (the `NA`'s can also be the number of occurrences period):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA    2    0    1
[2,]    -   NA    0    2
[3,]    -    -   NA    1
[4,]    -    -    -   NA
```

1. How can I convert the long data into a matrix in R? (without manual counting).
2. What is this type of metric is called? It's not a typical 'contingency' table.
3. After the table is created, what's the best way to plot the resulting matrix with colors denoting the count/frequency?

Comment: 1) Do you already have some code? If yes, could you post it?
2) Right now you just have a matrix showing a surjective function
3) This highly depends on the message your plot should tell others. You could use stacked barplots.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!
1) I don't have any code to go from the long data to the matrix. That's what I need the most help on.
2) Yes, essentially, what I want is a matrix (or rather the upper triangle, since the lower is the same) that has counts of how frequently 2 things cooccur.
3) I was thinking along the lines of a matrix with colors to denote frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Test this

```
r1 = sort(unique(df1$response))
r2 = split(df1$response, df1$person)
ans = sapply(seq_along(r1), function(i)
    rowSums(sapply(r2, function(x) (r1[i] %in% x) * (r1 %in% x))))
diag(ans) = NA
ans
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   NA    2    0    1
#[2,]    2   NA    0    2
#[3,]    0    0   NA    1
#[4,]    1    2    1   NA
```